# How to include Custom files in C++ program

Tags: c++

How to include file 2 in file 1. What changes I need to make in file 2.

file 1

```
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout<<"Hello World";

return 0;
}
```

file 2

```
 int otheFun()
 {
   cout<<"Demo Program";
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Question makes no sense. You can't have two programs in one. What would the functionality be? Which `main` would execute?

Comment: You need to explain what effect you're trying to get. What do you want to happen?

Answer (score 11):

You do not include cpp files in to another cpp files.
Also, a c++ program can have only one `main()` function.
If you are trying to play around with a program which has multiple files, You will need to have something like this:

**file2.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "file2.h"


int printHelloWorld()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello World";

    return 0;
}
```

**file2.h**

```
 #ifndef FILE2_H    <----Lookup Inclusion Guards on google, this is important concept to learn.
 #define FILE2_H

 int printHelloWorld();

 #endif //FILE2_H
```

**file1.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "file2.h"


 int main()
 {
     std::cout<<"Demo Program";
     printHelloWorld();
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: How about creating header and then including??

Comment: @sandbox: Including what? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: learing to create header file...eg: file2.h

Answer (score 1):

> What changes I need to make in file 2?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello world";
   cout << "Demo Program";
}
```

Comment: Should do what the OP wants, although you forgot `using sarcasm;`.

Comment: @peachykeen: I knew I'd forgotten _something_...!

Comment: can I propose another change ?